# MaterialUI slider with multiple colours

Tags: css, material-ui

I am getting into MaterialUI at the moment and specifically I want to create a range slider. I am using this example https://material-ui.com/components/slider/#range-sliders

What I am trying to achieve is to have different colours for "high", "medium" and "low" range. The result should be something similar to:

[image: Multi-colour slider]

The colour of the thumbs doesn't really matter but I want to clearly distinguish the different ranges on the rail.

Is there anyway to achieve that?

Comment: Material UI didn't support that yet, You can only have two colors the default bar and the active one by CSS... https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/1653

Comment: You might be able to achieve this using a gradient. See my example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59744468/how-to-add-linear-gradient-color-to-slider/59754739#59754739.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this coloured range [MUI](https://mui.com) Slider (normal/reversed) implemented in the codepen: https://codesandbox.io/s/metrics-color-threshold-slider-reversed-o58nu6.

Answer (score 2):

Hey I think I solved this in a decent way using the ThumbComponent component input on the slider which I noticed when having two thumbs their data-index properties were different.

```js
function MyThumbComponent(props) {
  if (props['data-index'] == 0) {
    props.style.backgroundColor = "green"
  } else if (props['data-index'] == 1) {
    props.style.backgroundColor = "red"
  }
  return (
    <span {...props}>
    </span>
  );
}
```

Output screenshot sorry I'm not use to answering on stack:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1HUC.jpg (I can't embed in answer)

Finally and most usefully here is the codepen: https://codesandbox.io/s/dualrange-two-colors-fzifz

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: tracks are not colored