# Is there in JSS an equivalent of background color + image?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

I am using JSS in React to style Material UI components. I have tried to surf on the web the equivalent of the code bellow from CSS in JSS, but I was unsuccessful.

```
 background: 
    linear-gradient(
      rgba(64, 153, 255, 0.5), 
      rgba(64, 153, 255, 0.5)
    )    
    ,
   url('myUrl');
```

Can somebody help me figure out if there is a way to achieve the same result in JSS.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working example of the correct syntax. The entire value for the background-image (linear-gradient is an image not a color) goes into a single string.

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  gradientAndUrl: {
    width: "400px",
    height: "400px",
    backgroundImage:
      "linear-gradient(rgba(64, 153, 255, 0.5), rgba(64, 153, 255, 0.5)), url(https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/10000/velka/black-monkey-11280155875i3QV.jpg)"
  }
});

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <div className={classes.gradientAndUrl} />;
}
```

[image: Edit Background image gradient and URL]

Related answer: [How to add linear-gradient color to Slider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59744468/how-to-add-linear-gradient-color-to-slider/59754739#59754739)

Comment: Thanx Ryan, this worked. My confusion was that I was thinking that Gradients are colors, now I know that they are background Images. Once I used them as a background image along with an other image, it worked as a charm. Thanx again